# iPhone Device compatibility for iOS 8.1

Tags: ios

I recently updated my xcode from 5 to xcode 6.1 with ios 8.1..
 My application works well on iPhone 4s,5,5s, 6 and 6 plus.
But I cannot run my application on iPhone 3gs(with ios 6.0)..
Is there any way i can run my application on iOS 6.0?
is os upgrade for the mobile, the only option?

Kindly help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Xcode 5 again, and have it side by side with Xcode 6. Once you have it on your machine, you can run iOS6 simulator from 5 and run app.